# How to search data from mysql database table which store json data?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

In Mysql Database I have a table called : `label_data` which have 4 columns 1) id, 2) cdid, 3) ctid 4) label_data

This `label_data` column contain following JSON data :

```
{"cdid":"26236","work_phone":"3150-1708","mobile_phone":"090-6858-4306",
"email":"inoue_r@work.com","email_private":"inoue@gmail.com"}
```

So is there any way to get `email` key `value` ? I mean you can see in JSON data `email` has value `inoue_r@gmail.com`. So what is the Mysql Query to get `email` value ? I wan to use it in `WHERE` clause

I am trying it with this but no luck :

```
$search = "ou";
$ano = "SELECT * FROM contact_label WHERE label_data LIKE '%".$search."%' ";
```

Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: why would you store full json on database, The main reason of databases is opposite of what you are doing.

Comment: What is the name of table contact_label or  label_data?

Comment: If you want to store json...then why not go with nosql DB like mongoDB. Also searching by using like will result in wrong result and also it is an expensive call